# how to grant site app permissions to subsites using powerShell in SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, powershell, office-365

I have a top level site it contains 100+ subsites i want add workflow app permissions to each site, its bit time taking by doing manually [like this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/3f3dd793-23a3-45c3-bda7-ad3b33e644c1/site-app-permissions?forum=sharepointgeneral). 
i am looking powershell scripts to automate/one time fix. 
could you please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint supports four different permission scopes within the content database and tenancy, those scopes are Tenancy,Site Collection, web , List. 
You just need to define the scope for the app permission instead of adding it to each sub site.

**Tenancy** 
The tenancy where the add-in is installed. Includes all children of this scope.

```
<AppPermissionRequests>
    <AppPermissionRequest Scope=”http://sharepoint/content/tenant” Right=”FullControl” />
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

**Site Collection**
The site collection where the add-in is installed. Includes all children of this scope.

```
<AppPermissionRequests>
    <AppPermissionRequest Scope=”http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection” Right=”FullControl” />
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

reference : [Add-in permissions in SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/add-in-permissions-in-sharepoint)